# How to open a drawer by clicking hamburger icon in header in react native?

Tags: react-native

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Block } from 'galio-framework';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function Header(props) {

return (
    <Block style={ styles.header }>
        <Block>
            <Ionicons name="md-menu" size={32} color="grey" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
            <Text style={ styles.title } p>{ props.title }</Text>
        </Block>
        <Block>
            <Ionicons name="md-search" size={32} color="grey" />
        </Block>
    </Block>
)
}
```

When clicking on the hamburger icon I get this error:

```
RefererenceError: Can't find variable: Navigation
```

If I change my code to:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props)
```

This is one of my files where I am importing Header:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Block, Input, Button, Card } from 'galio-framework';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from '../../common/Header';

class Accountant extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Block style={ styles.blockStyle }>
                <Header title="Accounts" />
                  <Button onlyIcon icon="right" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Projects')}>

                  </Button>
            </Block>
        );
    }
}
```

I am using nested navigation. Here is my App.js file:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const DrawerAccountant = createDrawerNavigator();

function AccountantDrawer() {
  return (
    <DrawerAccountant.Navigator initialRouteName="Accountant">
      <DrawerAccountant.Screen name="Accountant" component={AccountantScreen} />
      <DrawerAccountant.Screen name="My Account" component={MyAccountScreen} />
    </DrawerAccountant.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Screen name="Accountant" component={AccountantDrawer} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Projects" component={ProjectsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Tasks" component={TasksScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="My Account" component={MyAccountScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default App;
```

The navigation drawer is working in the screens: "Accountant" and "My Account". The drawer opens when I click the menu icon in header. But it's not working in the screens: "Projects" and "Tasks".

Comment: That because of your ```header``` component not config with navigation. There are multiple ways to fix this problem if you need more help, share your parent component.

Comment: I have shared my parent component by editing the question.

Comment: Did you able to access navigation props inside ```Accountant```?

Comment: Yes, I edited in my question.

Comment: which version of navigation is it ?

Comment: It is 5.x version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your navigation props to child component

```
<Header title="Accounts" navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

then you can access your navigation from `Header` as below

```
<Ionicons name="md-menu" size={32} color="grey" onPress={() => props.navigation.openDrawer()} />
```

or you can use [withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/with-navigation/)

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Its working in some files but not working in others. I am getting error TypeError: props.navigation.openDrawer is not a function.

Comment: I will share my App.js file.

Comment: since we are passing navigation props to ```header``` component you can access ```props.navigation.openDrawer()```.  So pass navigation props to other components as well.

Comment: I did that. But still I got error. I think there is some problem in my nested navigation in App.js. Even if I side from left the drawer does not open in Projects and Tasks components.

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar that's because you didn't add those screens to your drawer, try to add those like ```<DrawerAccountant.Screen name="Projects " component={Projects } />```

Comment: I have a doubt. I don't want to add all the screens to the drawer. But the openDrawer should be working on those screens. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you can't achieve that. If you want to open the drawer in some specific screen you have to add that to your drawer container.

Comment: Do you know how to add an image or text in the header of the drawer?